# Possible to trigger the same true false event on two different component instances independently

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two popup components being called, one with the class prop `contentbox` and other "contentbox2"

They are shown if `isActive = true` and close if false.

currently closing any one of them closes both. I'm wondering if it is possble to trigger them independently from each other or will I need to assign them different event names.

Here is my popup component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div :class="theme" v-if="isActive" >
      <!-- <slot></slot> -->
      <div class="headerbar">
        <div class="htitle"><h3>Title Goes Here</h3></div>
        <div @click="$emit('close')" class="xbutton"><h1>X</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div >
      <img class="van" :src="`./assets/images/${img}`" />
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    mode: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: null,
    },
    img: String,
    theme: String,
    
    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: true,
      
    };
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit('close', this.isActive = !this.isActive)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is where the popup is called

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="icon">
      <button @click="isActive = !isActive">
        <img src="/assets/images/icon.jpg" alt="profile" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="/assets/images/yagihip.gif" alt="profile" />
    </div>
    <popup class="contentbox" v-if="isActive" img="van.gif" @close="testEmit" />
    <big-popup />
    <popup class="contentbox2" v-if="isActive" img="yagi.png" @close="testEmit"> </popup>
    
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
 
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: true,  
    };
  },
  methods: {
    testEmit(){
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
      console.log('test')
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitively need **2 separate states** in the parent component.

E.g. `contentBox1isActive` and `contentBox2isActive` instead of just `isActive`.

Or you use an array of component identifiers, like

```
isActive = [ contentBox1, ... ]
```

Alternatively you could use a similar array to hold the necassary attributes an display the dialog components with a [`<div v-for=...>` directive.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html).

To **close the correct component** you can either define separate close Handlers, like

```
closeComponent1(){ ... },
closeComponent2(){ ... },
```

or you give each component an identifier, pass that to the components event emitter, which passes it back to the event handler.
E.g.:

```
// parent:

<popup componentId="component1" ... @close="closeHandler">
...
closeComponent( componentId ){ ... },

// component:

props: {
    componentId: String,
},
...    
this.$emit('close', this.componentId)
```